# How to prove immediate predecessor by proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

My question says:

Let A be a nonempty set and let P(A) be partially ordered by set inclusion. Show that if B is in P (A) and x is not in B, then B is an immediate predecessor of B ∪ {x}.

I started by saying:

let C be in A s.t. B is a subset of C and C is a subset of B ∪ {x}.

Suppose C does not equal B and C does not equal B ∪ {x}.

Then C is a subset of B and B ∪ {x} is a subset of C. From the first subset since we assumed x is not in B then x is not in C. Now for the second subset since x is not in C, x is not in B ∪ {x}. But this is a contradiction since x is in B ∪ {x}. Then C=B or B ∪ {x}=C.

**update**

let C be in A s.t. B is a subset of C and C is a subset of B ∪ {x}.

Suppose C does not equal B and C does not equal B ∪ {x}.

Then We have proper sets B subset C and C subset B U {x}.

Now let y be in C\B and z be in B U {x}\C.

Then y is in C and y is not in B. z is in B U {x} and z is not in C

Then y,z is in (B U {x})\B. y in B or y in {x} and y not in B. z in B or z in {x} and z not in B.  So y,z in {x}. y in {x} means y=x. z in {x} means z=x. Then y=x=z and y=z. This is a contradiction. Thus B=C or B U {X} =C. B is a predecessor of B U {x}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $B\subseteq C\subseteq B\cup\{x\}$, and you’re assuming (to get a contradiction) that $C\ne B$ and $C\ne B\cup\{x\}$. This is fine, but it does not imply that $B\cup\{x\}\subseteq C\subseteq B$, which is what your’e saying at the beginning of the last paragraph. It says that $B\subsetneqq C\subsetneqq B\cup\{x\}$.

From this you can infer that there is some $y\in C\setminus B$ and some $z\in(B\cup\{x\})\setminus C$. Then $y\ne z$ (why?), and $y,z\in(B\cup\{x\})\setminus B$ (why?). But then $y=x=z$, so $y=z$, which is the desired contradiction.

Comment: What does the \ symbol mean?

Comment: @Sam: Set difference. It’s pretty standard nowadays to write $C\setminus B$ instead of the old-fashioned $C-B$.

Comment: Hmm okay I'm going to take a look at how I can redo it and update what I find. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam: You’re welcome.

Comment: Oh wait. If we assume C not equal to B and C not equal to of B U {x} can't we say instead C is not a subset of B And B U {X} is not a subset of C?

Comment: @Sam: Yes, but that just tells you that $B\subsetneqq C\subsetneqq B\cup\{x\}$, which is what you really need.

Comment: Okay got it. I redid it. Do I write what I got now in my original post?

Comment: I still haven't updated my changes

Comment: @Sam: (Didn’t mean to jump the gun.) You write: ‘Then B is not a subset of C and C is not a subset of B U {x}.’ This is false: $B$ **is** a subset of $C$, and $C$ **is** a subset of $B\cup\{x\}$. Those facts are given: we chose $C$ that way. What is true is that $B$ is a ***proper*** subset of $C$, and $C$ is a ***proper*** subset of $B\cup\{x\}$.

Comment: Okay so I can keep the fact that they are subsets because we assumed this? But then do we proceed the same after that?

Comment: @Sam: Yes, the rest of that paragraph is okay. At the beginning of the next paragraph you know that $z$ is in $B\cup\{x\}$ but not in $C$, and since $B\subseteq C$, that means that $z$ can’t be in $B$, either. Thus, $z\in(B\cup\{x\})\setminus B$. You know that $y\in C$ and $y\notin B$; can you see now why $y\in B\cup\{x\}$? Once you fill in that detail and fix the beginning of the previous paragraph, you’ll be in business.

Comment: Hmm y is in B U {x} because C is a subset of B U {X} and since y is in C y has to be in B U {x}? I just am wondering then do we ever use the fact that we are given x is not in B?

Comment: @Sam: If $x$ were in $B$, then $B\cup\{x\}$ would be equal to $B$; $B$ is not a predecessor of itself, so $B$ would not be a predecessor of $B\cup\{x\}$, let alone an immediate predecessor.

Comment: Ah okay so this does not need to be used in the proof? It's just understood if x were in B then we wouldn't thane the case of union? Does what I said before make sense for why y is in B U {X}.?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, I meant to say that in my previous comment: yes, that’s why $y\in B\cup\{x\}$. \\ The result really is about what happens when you add a single *new* element to a set $B$, so we’re interested only in that case. The point of the exercise is the intuitively obvious fact that adding one element to $B$ is the smallest possible increase: there is no set $C$ that both properly contains $B$ and is properly contained in the bigger set $B\cup\{x\}$.

Comment: That makes more sense to me when explained that way. I'm going to update it one last time to make sure I got it all right. I'm just going to organize my thoughts first

Comment: @Sam: Okay; leave a comment when you’ve updated it, and I’ll take a look.

Comment: Okay I updated it.

Comment: @Sam: Almost. *Proper set* isn’t meaningful by itself; where you wrote *Then We have proper sets*, you need *Then* $B$ *is a proper subset of* $C$, *and* $C$ *is a proper subset of* $B\cup\{x\}$. (And at the end you have a typo, *contraction* instead of *contradiction*.)

Comment: I made those small changes. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Sam: Yep; you’re in business now.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @Sam: You’re welcome!